# Connect Nodejs Faye-Client to Rails Faye server

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, node.js, faye

I have a Faye server running under Rails (with redis backend) and would like to allow a nodejs script to communicate with my clients via Faye. Therefore I need to connect my Nodejs Faye client to the Rails process, that runs Faye.

Using:

```
var client = new faye.Client('http://localhost:6379/faye');
//I also tried ports 3000 and 8000 and verified that redis runs at 6379

faye.Logging.logLevel = 'debug'
faye.logger = function(msg){
    console.log(msg)
}

client.connect();
```

I only see:

> [Faye.Client] Initiating handshake with "undefined//undefinedundefined"
>
> [Faye.Dispatcher] Selected
>   "long-polling" transport for "http://localhost:6379/faye"
>
> [Faye.Client] Passing through "outgoing" extensions:
>   {"channel":"/meta/handshake","version":"1.0","supportedConnectionTypes":["in-process","websocket","long-polling"],"id":"1"}

Do I really need to start a nodejs-faye-server as well to configure it to use redis, or shouldn't it be enough to have NodeJS acting as a client to Rails? Unfortunately [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20404204/1994642) did not help me. Has anybody ever done this? If so, how?

Answer (score 0):

Found the answer. Turned out the problem was not in the NodeJS script, but in the way I started in from Ruby. Turns out that `system` waits for value to be returned and thus does not process the Faye-message. Using `spawn()` solved the issue.